# How to display the output from a function in a text wdiget with PYSIMPLEGUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

How would I display the results from the function in the pop-up text output?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

FILMS = [["There will be blood", "Paul Thomas Anderson", 2007],
      ["Lion King","Rob Minkoff", 1994],
      ["Toy Story","Josh Cooley",1995],
      ["Monty Python's Life of Brian","Terry Jones",1979],
      ["Die Hard","John McTiernan",1988],
      ["Rocky","John G. Avildsen",1976]]


def listprint():
    for i in range (len(FILMS)):
        print(FILMS[i][0])

event, values = sg.Window('Find a film', [[sg.Text('Are you ready:')],[sg.B("OK",key="-OK-"), sg.B("Return",key="-Return-")] ]).read(close=True)

if event == '-OK-':
    sg.popup('Film names will be printed in the python output:',command = listprint)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the result to `sg.popup`, but using `*` to unpack list/tuple. Sometime, it looks not so well and you can use user defined popup window to show them.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def film_name():
    return [item[0] for item in FILMS]

FILMS = [
    ["There will be blood", "Paul Thomas Anderson", 2007],
    ["Lion King","Rob Minkoff", 1994],
    ["Toy Story","Josh Cooley",1995],
    ["Monty Python's Life of Brian","Terry Jones",1979],
    ["Die Hard","John McTiernan",1988],
    ["Rocky","John G. Avildsen",1976],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Are you ready:')],
    [sg.B("OK"), sg.B("Return")],
]

window = sg.Window('Find a film', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Return'):
        break
    elif event == 'OK':
        sg.popup('Film names will be printed in the python output:', *film_name())
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```